# Replace text with PHP code

Tags: jquery

i wonder how i can replace the link text with PHP code. I have this code:

```
<div class='rmm' data-menu-title = "Navigation" data-menu-style = "custom"> <!-- data-menu-title = Input your Menu text (This is the text to the right of the mobilestate menu)-->
<ul><li id="current_yes"><a href="#">HEM</a></li></ul>
</div>
```

And i want it to look loke this:

```
<div class='rmm' data-menu-title = "Navigation" data-menu-style = "custom"> <!-- data-menu-title = Input your Menu text (This is the text to the right of the mobilestate menu)-->
<ul><li id="current_yes"><a href="#"><?php echo $lang['MENU_HOME']; ?></a></li></ul>
```

So how to change this with jQuery on page load?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to change it using jQuery or are you trying to do it using PHP? The title ask about PHP but inside your question is asking about doing it with jQuery... I'm confused.

Comment: It is totally confusing, I think Patrik expect the PHP code to be executed when put into HTML with JS, but that is not the way it works: 1. User requests a response from within the browser to server. 2. Server creates HTML+JS Output with PHP. 3. HTML+JS get send to Browser. 4. HTML gets rendered, JS gets executed in the Browser. 5. goto 1. and repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to do this task on PHP side and not in browser/client side.

To achieve it using jQuery you must to locate "a" tag with something unique, like its "id".

Try this:

HTML code:

```
<div class='rmm' data-menu-title = "Navigation" data-menu-style = "custom">
    <!-- data-menu-title = Input your Menu text
    (This is the text to the right of the mobilestate menu) -->
<ul>
    <li id="current_yes">
         <a href="#" id="link_I_want_to_change">HEM</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#link_I_want_to_change").html("Place your text here");
    });//]]>
</script>
```

Try it online here:
http://jsfiddle.net/OscarGarcia/g1wfeqkc/

Good luck!

Comment: What happened again? Another negative vote without a comment or explanation? What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: Hello, and thak you. Im testing it now. I'l get back to you.

Comment: Hey, it's not realy working it is the HEM text i whant to change to whatever comes from <?php echo $lang['MENU_HOME']; ?> i have at start of page this: <?php include_once 'common.php';?> and in this file i have this: $lang['MENU_HOME'] = 'Home';

Comment: When you let JS put PHP code into the HTML markup your Browser already rendered, how would you expect the server to execute the PHP code IN YOUR BROWSER? Please read something about the concept of Server- and Clientside.

Comment: That's the point. It's better to do this task on server/PHP side than JavaScript/client side. The second block of code (with PHP tags) is better because client browser receive the translated string inside HTML (rendered).

Answer (score 0):

Hey i got it like this:

```
<div class='rmm' data-menu-title = "Navigation" data-menu-style = "custom"> <!-- data-menu-title = Input your Menu text (This is the text to the right of the mobilestate menu)-->
<ul><li id="current_yes"><a href="#" id="1">HEM</a></li></ul>
</div>

<script>
var word = 'HEM';
var sent = $('#1').html().replace(word, '<?echo $lang['MENU_HOME']; ?>'); 
$('#1').html(sent);
</script>
```